# query time-out after database restore

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I have a CLR compiled stored procedure in SQL server 2008 which has always worked fine.
But after a database restore it suddenly stopped working. It times out. Running the query with the same parameters from SSMS takes only 2 seconds to complete.

I've dropped and recreated it, tried DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and rerun, all to no avail. it keeps timing out. I cant take down the db as it is used heavily.

Since it is a CLR compiled SP I doubt it is a parameter sniffing problem.

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Read  Erland Sommarskog's article [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: actually I was reading that right now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aha! The problem was that after a db restore the query optimization statistics should be run again, they didnt run automatically because the tables that caused the slowdown dont grow fast.

UPDATE STATISTICS 'tablex' fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this command?

```
       ALTER DATABASE SomeDatabase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

Comment: it did not make a difference

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL server profiler output when the SP times out? Does it have correct params?

Comment: yes parameters are correct and querying with the same parameters in SSMS takes like 1 second

Comment: Then the issue could be user permission related. Have you tried running the SP in SSMS with different credentials?

Comment: played around with different users a little but it has no effect. The query worked a few times after putting recovery model to 'simple' but then it started timing out again when nothing was changed

Comment: When you re-create the SP, did you mark it as UNSAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS? If you marked it as SAFE, the caller would not be able IMPERSONATE using windows identity in case your dll wants that. Also try increasing command timeout of your front end app. CLR compiled SPs use SqlPipe objects to send results back to the client. The pipe can only send results through the connection that the request came from. If there are connection failures in between request and result, the Sqlpipe will fail.

Comment: The permission level is "safe", so thats why theres no performance difference when running the query as another user? I did end up increasing the CommandTimeOut and then it worked again but Im still puzzled why it worked before the database restore. Guess its better to let it go at this point and cut my teeth in it again next time something like this happens. Thanks for the tips anyways!